# Contains in Linq to Object?

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects

I have the following Lists :

```
var list1 = new List<string> {"m1", "m2", "m3"};
var list2 = new List<List<string>> 
    {
        new List<string>{"m1", "m2", "m3"},//1
        new List<string>{"m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"},//2
        new List<string>{"m4", "m5", "m3", "m45", "m35"},//3
        new List<string>{"m1", "m36", "m43", "m54", "m54"},//4
        new List<string>{"m2", "m4", "m3", "m44", "m55"}//5
    };
```

I wanna select each list of `list2` that contains all elements of list1.
How should we do it in an optimize way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do use the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) methods:

```
var results = list2.Where(x => !list1.Except(x).Any())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list2.Where(l2 => list1.Intersect(l2).Count()==list1.Count)
```

Comment: +1 This would work too, although I still prefer `Any()` for performance.